# Sublime Text 3: How do I stop flagrantly incorrect tab suggestions?

Tags: html, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Where in my settings is autocomplete failing to decipher what it's suggesting? This is obviously syntactically incorrect, I'm inside the quotes for a tag and it's suggesting more tags.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way Sublime Text scopes work. Autocompletion is based on the scope of the character immediately to the right of the caret when there is no selection. In your example, it is the `"` character. It therefore doesn't see that the caret is actually inside the `style` attribute, because it sees CSS as only what is between the quotes, and not the quotes themselves. Therefore, it suggests other attribute names.

The workaround is simply to ensure there is a space between where you are typing and the closing `"` character of the attribute value.

[image: demo of caret position importance]

EDIT: I have now suggested a fix for this in [a PR to the SublimeText Default Packages repo](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/532). If it gets accepted, it will be available in the next ST3 build. Alternatively, you can follow the instructions in the repo's Readme to grab the changes sooner.

EDIT: and [another PR](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/586) to make the same fix when typing just before the `</style>` tag.

Comment: Yeesh, that is egregious, thanks for the explanation.
One thing, though, when I manually use single quotes, the scope works just fine no matter what follows or where my cursor is. Why would this happen? Alternatively, is there an easy way to force Sublime to autocomplete the style attribute to be =' ' instead of =" ", since it works with the former.
[Example](http://i.imgur.com/nmAf089.png)

Comment: ah, looks like an inconsistency in the syntax definition is causing the single quotes to be treated as CSS. To change the HTML autocomplete behavior, you'd basically need to modify [this line](https://github.com/forkeith/Packages/blob/b7161af294745a1310f202a6cd182e86a34d94ae/HTML/html_completions.py#L394). Not sure if it qualifies as easy, but you could do so using https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer